# program fails to join thread used for server socket

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a GUI and i need to be able to open a server socket that listens to incoming traffic, but when I try to join the server thread it gives an error:

RuntimeError: cannot join current thread

Here is the relevant code:

```
def create_widgets(self):

  ...other widgets...

  self.thread1 = threading.Thread(target = self.serverstart)
  self.button2 = Button(text = "Start", command = self.thread1.start)
  self.button2.grid(row=2, column=3)

def serverstart(self):
  import tcpServer
  tcpServer.start(self.intip)
  self.thread1.join()
```

Here is the code for tcpServer:

```
import socket

def start(intip):
  host = intip
  port = 5000

  s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6)
  s.bind((host, port))

  s.listen(1)
  c, addr = s.accept()
  print "Connection from: " + str(addr)
  while True:
          data = c.recv(1024)
          if not data:
                  break
          print "from connected user: " + str(data)
          data = str(data).upper()
          print "sending: " + str(data)
          c.send(data)
  c.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
      start()
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*RuntimeError: cannot join current thread* means that the current thread is trying to join itself.

Indeed, you launch your thread routine (bound method `serverstart`) and store the returned thread.  That routine, then, attempts to join that thread ... which is itself.  *RuntimeError*

Comment: Ah, thank you. Python programming, and programming in itself, is a new field for me so I have lot to learn.

Comment: You're welcome.  Don't hesitate to upvote and accept if this answer solved your problem.

Comment: I would certainly upvote it, but since I'm a new user I don't unfortunately have enough reputation to do so